# iTextSharp 5.5.13.3 GetLicenseeInfoForVersion Issue

Tags: c#, itext

This is a very strange one, been using this Nuget package for years, never an issue. However on new PC my local project is having an issue with the following code:

`MethodInfo method = licenseKeyClass.GetMethod("GetLicenseeInfoForVersion", types);`

I've tried, removing and re-installing iTextSharp Nuget package, no joy, deleting my local copy, cloning the project from Git, still no joy, yet on my old PC works like a charm.

I have also cleared my Nuget Cache in Visual Studio 2022, cleared from my local windows profile .nuget\packages. Cleaned project, forced Nuget to download iTextSharp 5.5.13.3 and itextsharp.xmlworker 5.5.13.3. No matter what I do the debug process fails at line 91 in Version.cs.

Other developers can run the same project/branch codebase with no issues.

I've not modified the source code, so using in compliance with GNU Affero General Public License, therefore not requiring a Commercial License.

Any thoughts?

Please no suggestions re upgrading to itext7, employer development restrictions prevent moving to .NET Core at this moment in time.

Comment: What exactly _is_ the issue you have?

Comment: System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'    at iTextSharp.text.Version.GetInstance() in iTextSharp.text\Version.cs:line 91

I don't get this on my old pc with same project/branch neither does any other developer.

Comment: Can keep hitting F5 for every time it is called (54 times in this instance), I do end up with a PDF.

Comment: In the original iTextSharp 5.5.13.3 line 91 of Version.cs is in a multi-line comment. So if you get that error at that line, there is something fishy, your execution appears not to use the original iTextSharp 5.5.13.3 code.

Comment: Not sure what is fishy about 'using (var offerMemoryStream = new MemoryStream())
{ using (var document = new Document(PageSize.A4, 25, 25, 30, 30)) { PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, offerMemoryStream);'

        document.Open();'

Comment: It is fishy that you get that error. If it's harmless, you by some error actually use a different official iTextSharp version.  If it's harmful, someone injected a patched version onto your system that does who knows what.

Comment: Just using Nuget via Visual Studio 2022 to obtain the package. Other developers have no issues with the same project/branch codebase, nor do I on my old PC. Happy to download the package from a link you can supply, this is bizarre beyond words.

Answer (score 1):

When the error occurs in Visual Studio 2022, in the error dialog box, just check the option stop when the error raised by itextsharp.dll. Then it will continue execution and the report is generated successfully.